The Sol in my wallet was transferred without my permission
All I did was install phantom wallet and send sol from my exchange to phantom wallet and then create @username.
As soon as I created @username, UI updated and my SOL disappeared. When I checked SOL scan, it was sent to another wallet.
I didn't send it, my mnemonic was not leaked and no one else was with me. Does anyone know about this phenomenon? I will attach TXID.
my wallet address: C1y2zyEfV21nB8ugEH85t4ZvuLTYd8Ee2pvaNw8ATNFv
first transaction Txid (What I sent) : 3P6YLkiQTAF2E5pBNrceG1Pf2DnTU45vVpinKvHbm7WJVhjYVHRLZfkmLoeHuNrah2Jp2CdQQqpD1xTEsiBzNSYn
second transaction Txid (What I didn't send) : 5f7VRxamydzUAzPJGbbzLmaHrzJq4VGo2gWQv3Epqsh1hqFBJAn3NCSXAfBpsh75vZdXxx5YgE6jS6boGwsaPshq

please answer me, It's frustrating, I'm going crazy
